# How to copy from one stream to another?

Tags: c++

I was wondering what the best approach is, performance wise, to copy a data sequence from an arbitrary binary file into another binary file, using C++ fstream library.

The sequence size can be anything, from a few bytes, to hundreds of megabytes.

One approach is of course by using an intermediate memory buffer. If this is the correct approach, what size would you consider for the intermediate buffer?

What would an alternative (better) approach be?

Edit: 
I should mention that the requirement is to copy from an arbitrary position in the first stream, to an arbitrary position in the second stream.

Comment: If you don't need access to the data, you could just let the operating system do the copy for you. Since C++17 there is the [`std::filesystem::copy_file()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/copy_file) standard library function for exact this purpose.

Comment: I am, of course, not looking for a way to copy an entire file.

Answer (score 5):

This is typically done using the normal stream output operator `<<` to output the source streams buffer (which you get with [`rdbuf()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/rdbuf)):

```
output_stream << input_stream.rdbuf();
```

Comment: This is not what I am looking for, as I need to be able to copy a specific number of bytes from the input stream.

Comment: @FrustratedSoul Then there's really no way around you having to do the reading and writing yourself explicitly with your own buffer. At least as long as you only want to use standard portable C++.